# How to pull entries from a model based off their associated data? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tags, tagging

Let's suppose I have a Discussion model, and that a discussion can be tagged. These tags are associated to the discussion through a taggings table.

I want to define a method .tagged_with(tag) that will basically do:

```
 def tagged_with

      Discussion.where(#something about tags include the tag given)
 end
```

I do have some methods that might be helpful already set up. For example, I have tag_list

```
 def tag_list
     tags.map(&:name).joins(", ") #my tags are separated by commas, not spaces)
 end
```

And if someone knows an answer to the simpler question of trimming the Discussion model based off one tag, how can I expand it to be more adaptable - for example, accepting an argument of multiple tags, and being able to specify that any or all are necessary. EG:

```
 Discussion.tagged_with(tag1, tag2, :any => true)
```

FYI some of the code from the associations:

```
has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable
has_many :tags, :through => :taggings, :source => :tag, :source_type => "Tag"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to join the tags table into your Discussion query, through its has_many relationship. `Discussion.joins(:tags).where(:tags => {:name => array_of_tags})`.

With the below method definition, you can do something like `Discussion.tagged_with(['foo', 'bar'])` or `Discussion.tagged_with('foo')`.

```
def self.tagged_with(tag_or_tags)
  joins(:tags).where(:tags => {:name => tag_or_tags})
end
```

Comment: just to learn more, do you know how you would order by the number of matching tags in this method? IE if I search "Foo" and "Bar", how would I augment it to put discussions with BOTH foo and bar higher than those tagged with either one?

Comment: Hmm. You could theoretically do some gnarly SQL to change the order in the results, but it might be more sensible to do the sort afterward in Ruby. If you expect to have hundreds or more discussions returned, the better the idea to somehow do it in the database; if you will have fewer, it probably isn't worth the ugliness required for that query.

Comment: +1 Thanks pbyrne, just what I was looking for too. How would you do the opposite query, to find Discussions with tags NOT in the array_of_tags?

Comment: @dj: I think you should be able to do that like so (not tested in a console, so no guarantees that it'll work): `Discussion.joins(:tags).where("tags.name not in (?)", array_of_tags)`.